# How can I make sure only my VPN client can access public networks directly?

Tags: security, vpn, wifi

Presently, I go like this:

- Go to Starbucks
- Open my laptop (which may have 3 gmail accounts etc open in browser)
- Connect to their public network
- Sometimes have to press the "I agree" button in browser
- Wait for my VPN client (PrivateTunnel, but could be OpenVPN) to connect

And now I have secure access.

But I don't know which of the software running on my laptop had accessed the Internet in the meantime, before the VPN kicked in.

How do I disable the network for everybody but the VPN (And, possibly, the browser window where I may have to say "I agree")?

Answer (score 1):

You could try rejecting every port other than what is required. A PPTP VPN connection uses 1723 if I recall. Then maybe port 80 for the "I agree" and whatever is needed for core networking on your OS.

Everything else you could deny.

Then after the VPN connects disable the firewall rule.

Comment: Thank you, that partially solves it (provided I can control my firewall from command line).

Comment: Partially because how do I prevent gmail from contacting the server on the background?

Comment: You could control your firewall from the command line. In Linux the common one is ufw and in Windows it's some netsh syntax that's easy to google. It's worth noting you're gonna have to likely tweak and troubleshoot a bit to have this actually work. As for gmail contacting the server on the background, do you mind elaborating on this issue?

Comment: I mean, the ajax from gmail.com in my browser tab. It does contact its server periodically; something I'd only want to do via the tunnel (or my home network)

Comment: You could block gmail in your browser and lift it once the VPN is established but that's just another thing you'd have to lift and as such might not be worth it

Comment: You are right, not worth it. There has to be a Powershell script for it.